# are Cicadas kings or queens of the night?

Tags: semantics

Cicadas are insect that make sounds. They are very lout actually. Then, while talking about the night when cicadas do their work, one may say "The cicadas are kings" or "The cicadas are queens"?

In other words, the noun "cicada" is female or male? or there is a neutral-genre word for royalty?

Comment: There is no grammatical gender of nouns in English. Using kings or queens is poetical enough; there is no real cultural context that leans towards one or the other. One or the other will be fine.

Comment: All I know is they make a lot of noise.

Comment: Where I live they go all day long.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's based on an incorrect assumption, that all cicadas are of a single gender (or at least the incorrect assumption that they should be referred to as such).

Answer (score 4):

The cicadas which make noise are males, and their noise can be liberally interpreted as "Hey! Hot mama! Over here!"

However, they are not referred to as kings, just as female cicadas are not referred to as queens. The term "queen" is reserved for the single egg-laying female in a eusocial species community, such as bees, termites and ants. Any female cicada can lay eggs.

Even among eusocial insects, there is no species that I'm aware of which elevates a single male to permanent status as consort to the queen, and thus there are no "king" insects.